# Is a simple color enabled logger for Haskell available?

Tags: haskell, logging, yesod

I would like to change the color of a log message output to the terminal depending on log level, topic, etc.,.

The only logger I [found](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Util-Loggers.html) that does this in Haskell is part of the xmonad-contrib package, but I don't want to take a dependency on it since it is rather large.

I know that Yesod logs in color, but it is not obvious to me how to make its logger work outside of a Yesod web application.

I looked into [hslogger](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hslogger) which seems to be very similar to [System.Log.Logger](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hslogger/latest/doc/html/System-Log-Logger.html), but neither seem to have color support out of the box.

hslogger is extensible via custom `LogHandlers`, so possibly someone implemented one with color support?

Are there alternatives for logging in Haskell I have overlooked so far?

**EDIT:**

Following Don Stewart's advice, I implemented a [custom log handler](https://github.com/thlorenz/log-colorhandler) that works with hslogger and ansi-c in order to allow logging to the terminal in colors.

Comment: You may need to submit a patch, e.g. adding color combinators - http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ansi-wl-pprint/0.6.4/doc/html/Text-PrettyPrint-ANSI-Leijen.html#g:9

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try - implement a color enabled LogHandler and make it available or possibly get it pulled into hslogger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of May 2012, the available logging libraries for Haskell are:

- [hslogger](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hslogger) - the venerable logging framework [described in RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/sockets-and-syslog.html).
- [SessionLogger](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SessionLogger) - a simple logging framework

And some more specialized ones:

- [greg-client](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/greg-client) - a client to the greg distributed logging system
- [fast-logger](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fast-logger) - a logging system optimized for fast IO

None support ansi terminal coloring output. There are several libraries for ansi coloring, so that shouldn't be too hard to add. E.g.

- [ansi-terminal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ansi-terminal).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see another example of a color logger, have a look at Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger (logStdoutDev) in the wai-extra package. This changes color per-request, but it should serve as a good example.